# Any Flexbox Better dynamic Solution : for Responsive layout design

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to achieve below three layout - in a responsive way.

1st layout - default layout

[image: 1st layout - default layout]

2nd Layout - with "min-width:600px"

[image: 2nd Layout - with "min-width:600px"]

3rd Layout - with "min-width:700px"

[image: 3rd Layout - with "min-width:700px"]

Above three layout I have already achieved.
I have mentioned height "200px" for dark-blue and red colored divs, which is actually somewhat fixed. If at a later stage, content in it increases (hypothetically) - the design layout will fail I think.

Is there any better way of doing it dynamically and my design doesn't fail if content increases.
I tried to think of it but couldn't get any.

Just Asked this question for better learning.

I wanted to achieve it by using flexbox. Any other way is also appreciated.

Can someone point in right direction?

I have added my HTML and css code.

```css
/* default color of background */
.red {
  background: red;
}
.dark-blue {
  background: darkblue;
}
.light-blue {
  background: lightblue;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}

/* Container properties */
.container {
  /* mentioned 100% so that element inside takes full width i.e with id = container2 */
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

/* Responsive design proprties */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .dark-blue {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #container2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .dark-blue,
  .red {
    height: 200px;
  }

  .dark-blue {
    width: 25%;
    order: 2;
  }
  #container2 {
    width: 50%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .red {
    width: 25%;
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Layout shifter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box dark-blue"></div>
        <div class="container" id="container2">
            <div class="box light-blue"></div>
            <div class="box green"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box red"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you need to control both, height and width, CSS-Grid is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox has some advanatges and some downsides. one of the downsides is, that it is only good in controlling either height or width. Not both.

If you need to control both, CSS-Grid is the way to go.

Use `grid-template-areas` to place the divs. Its the equivalent to flex order.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
}

.dark-blue {
  grid-area: dark-blue;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.light-blue {
  grid-area: light-blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.green {
  grid-area: green;
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  grid-area: red;
  background-color: red;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      grid-template-areas:
        "dark-blue"
        "light-blue"
        "green"
        "red"
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      grid-template-areas:
        "dark-blue"
        "light-blue"
        "green"
        "red";
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 601px)
  and (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
      grid-template-areas:
        "dark-blue light-blue"
        "dark-blue green"
        "red red";
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 701px) {
    body {
      grid-template-areas:
        "red light-blue light-blue dark-blue"
        "red green green dark-blue"
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dark-blue"></div>
<div class="light-blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me understand well :)